# Ruby Telnet: How to send http request using telnet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby telnet library to make HTTP get request(http://127.0.0.1:3000/test) but i am not able to make http get request to my server.

Below is the code that i am trying

```
require 'net/telnet'  
webserver = Net::Telnet::new('Host' => '127.0.0.1', 'Port' => 3000, 'Telnetmode' => false)  
size = 0 
webserver.cmd("GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: 127.0.0.1/test") do |c|  
print c 
end
```

Please let me know what wrong i am doing here.

Comment: `telnet` is the wrong tool to speak HTTP in all cases. The only place where this is remotely acceptable is when using the `telnet` command on the command line which provides a mostly blank socket (but not fully, it will still break on edge cases). If you intend to speak raw HTTP, use a TCP socket instead.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968). Why do you want to use Telnet instead of HTTP? Telnet will take you down a rabbit hole, whereas HTTP will work very nicely with a HTTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to end your input HTTP with a carriage return and line ending, otherwise the HTTP server will wait for more headers:

```
webserver.cmd("GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n") do |c|
  print c
end
```

But telnet really isn't the right thing to use (unless you're just experimenting). If you want to make HTTP requests for a real-world program, you should definitely use a proper HTTP library (net/http at the least, or something like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) would be even better). HTTP seems simple, but there are many hidden complexities that mean creating a writer/parser from scratch is a lot of work.

Comment: i tried it but request that is hitting to the server is 127.1.0.1/ and not 127.0.0.1/test . its not working

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use telnet - your HTTP is malformed. The `Host` header should not include a path, that should come after GET. I've updated the answer. But don't use telnet for this!

Comment: Header lines must end with `\r\n` not just `\n`. Also, the headers must end with a single blank line, i.e. a GET request (without a request body) always ends with `\r\n\r\n`.